# error when trying to edit an entry in Visual Studio Lightswitch using sql server

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I get an error when I try to EDIT a data entry in lightswitch HTML Client app with SQL Server data. when I tried the same for tables created locally I didn't get the error. Also I got NO error when ADDING an entry and DB was updated successfully.

> the error:
>   Unhandled exception at line 21, column 12461 in http://localhost:52818/HTMLClient/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js
>
> 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-url='/ViewMilestones/'1st%20Silicon'/[b7758fa9e]']

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue today. My primary key was a string value (existing DB) LightSwitch can't handle string keys. I had to ask the DB admin to change the primary key to an integer column. So you need to change the primary key to an integer.

It's this part that causes your error:

```
'1st%20Silicon'
```

For me it was the redirect after the save method on the edit form that failed. The actual changes where getting saved in the db, but the GUI kept hanging.